# MAPI32.dll return messege 'FAILED API' in Windows 10 C#

Tags: c#, outlook, dllimport, mapi

I am using the following code snippet

```
[DllImport("MAPI32.DLL")]
public static extern int MAPISendMail(IntPtr session, IntPtr hwnd, MapiMessage message, int flg, int rsv);
```

After upgrading to Windows 10, my software features the message:

> 'FAILED API', in Log class is code 2.

I have not found a solution to this, but when I kill the Outlook process,
the error does not occur. Is someone having the same problem? How can I solve it?

Comment: So what does the function return?

Comment: Could be a permissions issue. Try running your app and outlook at the same privilege level.

Comment: Return code 2 Alex K.

Comment: Johnny, I realized this...